# How to store a special folder path in Settings.settings c#?

Tags: c#, special-folders, settings.settings

I am trying to insert in [Settings.settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDEcr.png) a special folder path (MyDocuments).
I currently use this: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` but hardcoded. I don't want to have it hardcoded, so I've decided to move it to Settings.settings. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDEcr.png), I have to choose a Type but I can't find an appropriate type for a code sequence. 
What type should I use, so that it will be interpreted in code syntax? Thank you! :)

```
private void LoadTemplateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            //select template file via dialog
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\NEWFOLDER");

            System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog fileSelectDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog {
                Multiselect = false,
                InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\NEWFOLDER"
            };
        }
```

Comment: Please, share your actual code